# How to select first descendant of specific type with CSS Selector in complex html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to locate an `<input>` element in a very long and complex html document. The `<input>` element has an ancestor `<div>` element with an id attribute. Here is an example snippet of what I'm describing:

```
<div id="root">
    <header>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input value="First Name">
                <input value="Last Name">
            </form>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to locate the `<input>` element with the value of "Last Name"

I'm thinking I'd do it by finding the root `<div>` element by its id and then to find its second descendant of type `<input>`

I'm imagining it could look like this:

```
#root **some magic** {
    some styling
    }
```

To locate the "First Name" `<input>` I'd simply do:

```
#root input {
    some styling
    }
```

This will look through the `<div id="root">` element and find the first descendant of type `<input>`.

How can I find the second one using a method similar to this?

I realize that for this simple example I could simply specify the full CSS selector or Xpath but I'm dealing with huge html documents with a lot of nested elements that I need to locate.

I'll also be happy to use Xpath instead of CSS if it is possible through that.

Comment: Is that your actual html layout?  Or is the input in some other container? If the former, you could try `#root input:first-child`

Comment: The actual layout is coming from .jsx as the application was developed in the React library. I included this as an example snippet

Comment: You added [selenium] and [automated-tests] tags to this but I don't see any reference to using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your inputs are like in your example, you are able to use `first-child`:

```css
#root input:first-child {
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <header>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input value="First Name">
                <input value="Last Name">
            </form>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More information about:

- [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)
- [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)
- [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

If your HTML is a little more complex but all the inputs are still siblings, then you can try `first-of-type`:

```css
#root input:first-of-type {
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <header>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <div>some other elements</div>
                <input value="First Name">
                <div>some other elements</div>
                <input value="Last Name">
                <div>some other elements</div>
            </form>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if your inputs are not siblings, you will have to go up to their closest ancestor that are siblings and put the first child on that

More information about:

- [first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)
- [last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)
- [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Other helpful links:

[Some helpful nth-child recipes](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).

Comment: Could I say `#root input:second-of-type`?

Comment: #root input:nth-of-type(2)

Comment: if you want anything other than first or last, it would be `nth` - eg `nth-of-type(2)` or `nth-child(2)`

Comment: so when using `nth-of-type`, the elements don't have to be siblings at all?

Comment: Yes they do: The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type, based on their position among a group of siblings.

Comment: So if the two `input` elements are both wrapped in their own `div` elements, the `nth-of-type` is invalid. Do you know about anything else I could use instead?

Comment: Read my answer properly - it gives you that scenario and create a proper [mcve] with your actual html structure so we are not wasting time on fifty questions about something you have not shown

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want. This selects the first input child inner #root.

```css
#root input:nth-of-type(1) { 
    background: red;
}
```

Or do you want select the input which has the value "First Name" ?

```css
#root input[value="First Name"] {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I want to select the input which has the value "First Name" but ideally without using the  `[value="First Name"]` method as not all of the elements I need to locate have some value

Comment: ok, then my first selector and @Pete selectors should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

To select the input with value "Last Name" use the below CSS selector.

```
#root input[value="Last Name"] {
    background: red;
}
```

where root is the id of the div and input is the tag with value = "Last Name"